# Windows Server lastLogon & lastLogonTimestamp Issues

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

Just a preface:

I have tested a program I have just written on 4 different Windows Servers on 4 different domains.  The one I tested it on at first displayed to me all users, and all users' `lastLogon` attribute.  I can get this information off of any of their 12 domain controllers, and their on site exchange server.

The next client I tested this software on ran some issues.  I received 7 users that had the attribute `lastLogon`.  The rest Returned "Null" to my C# program.  I then proceeded to test with various Powershell scripts to verify that this was not an issue with my programming.  Powershell returned `12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM` for these users.  When I open the `Attribute Editor` of Active Directory, these users show up with dates as early as today.  I tested this on both of this client's domain controllers (they only have 2, smaller client) with the same results.

Finally, I tested it on the domain controller of the client who will be using this software.  It worked just fine.  Just as the first client's had worked.

First client configuration:

> Windows Server 2008 Standard on some, Enterprise on others.

Second client configuration:

> Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard on both machines

Third client configuration:

> Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter on the machine tested.

I do not accept the answer that the `lastLogon` property not being replicated is the answer.  That does not make sense.  It wouldn't work on any of these devices if that was the case.

ALSO, almost forgot, I have found that the `lastLogonTimestamp` attribute does not work on the 2nd client's configuration either.  Powershell tested to verify.

I'd love for some help getting to the bottom of this so that I can submit my code for use.

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: `that the lastLogon property not being replicated is the answer`?  Why, it is true.  It isn't replicated.  You said you get values for most users in some environments.  Did you get the exact SAME values from each DC, or did you just get values that may have been related to the last time they accessed that DC.

Comment: @Zoredache They may not be the same exact values.  I don't care about that.  My issue is when I get a `Null` and `12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM` Response.  These users have logged in consistently over months and months, and you are telling me that none of the servers have any information about them period?  I think that's very hard to believe, especially when it works perfectly on other domains.

Answer (score 0):

LastLogon is not replicated, LastLogonTimeStamp is replicated based on certain parameters and criteria. A NULL LastLogon for a given user on a given DC means that DC has never authenticated that user. They could have logged on to the domain, but they were validated by a different DC in the domain.

**Example 1:** Say you have a New York DC and a California DC. Unless those users frequently travel between sites, the lastLogon attribute will be NULL for California users when you query the New York DC. Because users in California are authenticated by the California DC, and LastLogon is a non replicated attribute. **Example 2:** When you build a new DC, the LogonAttribute will be NULL for everyone until its been running for a few weeks.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/

Answer (score 0):

I remember that this attribute was present, but not used when your domain functional level was below a certain value.
Are all these domains running at least Windows 2008 functional level? Maybe the one where you don't get the values is still on on 2003.